# PHP7.0 Phar issues with apache2

Tags: apache2, php-7, phar

I have created PHP file within a folder,

/var/www/folder/test.php:

```
<?php
echo "Test file called!" ;
```

I have then created a PHAR via the cli:

```
php -d "phar.readonly = 0" 
-r "(new Phar('/var/www/app.phar'))->buildFromDirectory('folder') ;"
```

I can call the PHP file directly from within the Phar when mod-php5 is enabled, but not when mod-php7.0 is?

```
$ apt-get install apache2
$ curl localhost/app.phar/test.php
Test file called!
$ apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-common php7.0*
$ a2dismod php5
$ a2enmod php7.0
$ service apache2 restart
$ curl localhost/app.phar/test.php
...
<title>File Not Found</title>...
<h1>404 - File /test.php Not Found</h1>
...
```

We currently run a mixture of Tomcat and Apache2 so are sadly invested in our way of deploying WAR and PHAR files.